# Probability measure may not be unique

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

The Probability measure µ: ℱ → ℝ is defined uniquely if µ is defined on P, a π system such that ℱ = σ(P). Show that if P is not a π system but ℱ = σ(P); µ, the Probability measure, may not be unique. (Hint: consider Ω = {1,2,3,4})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathscr F$ be the power set of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. The collection $\mathbb P = \{ \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,4\} \}$ generates $\mathscr F$ (check this) but does not uniquely determine a probability measure on $\mathscr F$. This is because the distinct measures given by
$$ \mu_1(\{i\}) = 1/4, \quad i \in \{1,2,3,4\} $$
and
$$ \mu_2(\{i\}) = \begin{cases} 1/3, & i \in \{1,3\} \\ 1/6, & i \in \{2,4\} \end{cases} $$
both yield $\mu_j(\{1,2\}) = \mu_j(\{2,3\}) = \mu_j(\{3,4\}) = 1/2$.